# why ide internal browser give Http 500 Internal server error

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

error.jsp

```
<body>
    <%@ page isErrorPage="true"%>

    <h2>Sorry, your application generating an exception</h2>

    Exception is : <%=exception %>

</body>
```

index.html

```
<form action="process.jsp">

    No1 : <input type="text" name="n1"><br><br>

    No2 : <input type="text" name="n2"><br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Divide">

 </form>
```

process.jsp

```
<%@ page errorPage="/error.jsp" %>

    <%
    String num1=request.getParameter("n1");

    String num2=request.getParameter("n2");

    int a = Integer.parseInt(num1);

    int b = Integer.parseInt(num2);

    int c = a/b

    out.println("Division of numbers is : "+c);
    %>
```

when  I devide any number by zero ide internal web browser give the "Http 500 server Internal error) and when i change the web browser it give me correct out put

Comment: jrbeddard can you  answer my question

Answer (score 0):

I found out that IE has a feature turned on by default - Show friendly HTTP error messages (goto tools-> internet options-> advanced -> uncheck show friendly HTTP error message).
then Execute in Eclipse IDE. Worked for me!